# Does reading from file currently open by another process stops its writes?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file

Let's suppose I have process *X* with code like below that opens some `file` that is currently used also by another process *Y*. Process *Y* is quite heavily writing new lines into `file`.

```
using (var file = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
{
    string line = null;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // do something with line
    }
}
```

I wonder how reads from `X` influences writes from `Y`? Will be writing blocked while file is open (in scope of using) in the process `X`? To be more precise, this is regarding .NET 4.5 on Windows.

Comment: Will *X* even be able to open the file?

Comment: @Brandon, will be, thanks to the flags provided do the `File.Open`, if the `Y` opened it in the right way. But this works.

Comment: I think you'll find that it depends on if you're streaming and when you flush buffers.

Comment: you've got the code written ... is there something stopping you from testing this? Have you tried it and you are having a problem? What is the problem?

Comment: Remember that reader *X* will get an EOF condition if it reads beyond the last data that writer *Y* has actually written (flushed) to the shared file. That means you may need to sleep and retry the read, or use some other mechanism to synchronize the reading and writing operations.

Comment: No, I/O from multiple processes (if permitted at all) is not serialized.

Answer (score 0):

I read from and write to files simultaneously all the time and have not had problems ... there are of course ways to screw it up, which is why you should include your particular problems if it isn't working for you.